# What is the practicality of using PhoneGap?

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova

I am currently doing some research in using PhoneGap instead of write different code for all platforms. In my mind, right off the bat, one con to this is, in fact, you aren't writing your applications natively. I ask myself, what does this mean?

1. Will there be a performance hit?
2. Does PhoneGap offer wrappers for all native functionality? Is the documentation enough to get by?
3. What kind of UI's would you want or need(i.e. JQuery) and do they have proper documentation? Do these frameworks work seamlessly across different platforms?
4. Since Adobe is now in the mix will PhoneGap eventually become obsolete and in the long term it just doesn't really matter?

I would like to hear any feedback/advice/suggestions for those that have tried PhoneGap. Also if there is a list of functionality PhoneGap doesn't provide could someone provide a link?

**EDIT: I should point out that I realize that a big motivation of using PhoneGap is so that one doesn't have learn multiple programming languages. I already know Objective-C and Java and I am just exploring the potential use of PhoneGap - so I am coming at this from a slightly different angle. I mentioned this in one of my comments below.

Comment: If you want to check out some html app examples check out: http://m.chromeexperiments.com/ This is not phonegap, but you could make all this using PhoneGap aswell. Just to let you know some possibilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short, objective answer:** It depends.

Specifically, whether PhoneGap/Cordova is appropriate for your project depends on your needs. There are a lot of PhoneGap-based projects out there, so it's obviously useful for *some developers*; only you can say whether you're likely to be in that group.

**More details:**

> Will there be a performance hit?

Yes. Whether that matters depends on your application.

> Does PhoneGap offer wrappers for all native functionality? Is the
>   documentation enough to get by?

No on the first question, but it's extensible, so you can always add your own native code if you need to. Only you can say whether the documentation is sufficient, but you can always look at the code if you need/want to.

> What kind of UI's would you want or need(i.e. JQuery) and do they have
>   proper documentation? Do these frameworks work seamlessly across
>   different platforms?

That would seem to depend on what you're doing and on what you already know. PhoneGap doesn't make much difference one way or the other here.

> Since Adobe is now in the mix will PhoneGap eventually become obsolete
>   and in the long term it just doesn't really matter?

Whether [Cordova](http://incubator.apache.org/cordova/) (the open-source software formerly known as "PhoneGap") survives and thrives depends on many factors:

- Are people using it?
- Do the people who use it contribute to it?
- What will Adobe decide to do with PhoneGap (the proprietary version)? Will they kill it? Enhance it? Add features so compelling that most people choose it over Cordova?

If Cordova makes sense for your application, by all means use it. Contribute to it, if you can, and it will become even more useful to you and to the rest of the world.

Comment: as I had mentioned below to Yusufs post one of the main capabilities that I am going to be looking for is Core Graphics and/or the Android equivalent. Web services is another issue. Can PG take information from a webservice using JSON and export the data as need by the native app(s)? I am sure there are other libraries that I need to mention but those are the two that I can think of now.

Comment: PhoneGap lets you write your app using JavaScript & HTML, and it lets you make calls to the native app for additional functionality. You could implement certain features in native code using Core Graphics and then drive those features from JavaScript, but if yours is a graphics-intensive app then PhoneGap may not be the right solution. You'd do well to simply start using it for a simple project to learn more about it so that you can make a choice informed by your own experience.

Answer (score 1):

For simple apps, PG will not be a performance hit.

PG has many but not all native functions. You can always write a plugin, but really who wants to?

PG may go away eventually, but probably not until after your app does.

Comment: One of the native functions that I am really going to be interested in is the Core Graphics methods for iOS. On the PhoneGap website it does state that it supports "Media" but to me that sounds more like Movies and Pictures rather than custom drawing with core graphics. Also i see "Network" but that doesn't really scream web services(JSON?)

Comment: @cspam, If you have heavy graphics requirements maybe you could get away with new capabilities in HTML5 but I'm not sure how those features are adopted in mobile device browsers. Since you are making an app with html/javascript, you can call web services with ajax requests. If there is something you need natively, you can write a plugin but keep in mind that you would need one plugin per mobile platform that you're wanting to build/distribute.

Comment: @jlafay. Thanks for bringing the plugins piece of this. If you need to write a plugin because PG doesnt offer a functionality that you need and like you said, you need to write the plugin for each device that you are targeting...then haven't defeated the purpose of not having to write separate pieces of code natively for each platform? What if you end up having to write 3 or 4 plugins? then thats a possible 8 different pieces of code that you would have to write. At some point it would have just been easier to start off native.

Comment: The only reason to write a plugin is if you already have a lot of HTML5 code from some other project and lack only one native function to complete your awesome app.

Comment: @YusufX, yes it definitely depends on what you want to do and it's something to keep in mind when considering PG. Since the question is very open and high level, it's hard to say what would need to be used.

Comment: @YusufX - I am going to assume, at the moment, that PG doesnt support wrappers for Core Graphics. We are talking about a lot of missing native functionality here that you would need to write plugins for. I am not familiar with how writing a plugin works(still working through that) but if i end up needing to write multiple plugins(as I pointed out from jlafays response) then thats a lot of extra work. The reason a lot of people want to use PhoneGap is that they dont want to learn multiple programming languages. I already know ObjC and Java so I am coming from the other angle here.